# Why class returned in eventClassNames of V5 is not applied?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

With fullcalendar v5.7.2 in Alpinejs 2 app I want to set different color for cells depending
on some property and reading here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/classname-input
I catch event :

```
                dayMaxEvents: true,
                views: {
                    dayGridMonth: {
                        editable: false
                    }
                },

                events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {    //get data from db for selected dates
                    self.select_year = parseInt(moment(info.start).format('YYYY'))
                    self.select_month = parseInt(moment(info.start).format('MM'))

                    var dataArray = {
                        '_token': '{{ $csrf_token }}',
                        'start': moment(info.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        'end': moment(info.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        'ad_categories': self.searchSelectedCategoryIds,
                        'users': self.searchSelectedUserIds,
                        'status': self.searchStatus,
                        'text': self.searchText
                    }
                    window.axios.post('/admin/get_ad_events', dataArray).then((response) => {
                        successCallback(response.data.events);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.error(error)
                        failureCallback(error)
                        popupAlert('Calendar', 'Run time error : ' + getErrorMessage(error), 'error')
                    });

                }, // events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {    //get data from db for selected dates

                eventClassNames: function(arg) {
                   // return 'fullcalendar_nearest_days'; // if to uncomment this line it does not work anyway

                   if (arg.event.extendedProps.is_past) {
                        return [ 'fullcalendar_nearest_days' ]
                     } else {
                        return [ 'normal' ]
                     }
```

I check and see that fullcalendar_nearest_days is returned, but it is's properties are not applied
and checking events code I do not see “fullcalendar_nearest_days” in events styling...

Which way is correct ?

**MODIFIED:**
fullcalendar_nearest_days is defined as :

```
.fullcalendar_nearest_days {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: yellow !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

and looking at generated code I found that fullcalendar_nearest_days is the latest class in "a" tag class definition:

```
  <div class="fc-daygrid-event-harness fc-daygrid-event-harness-abs"
                 style="visibility: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;"><a
                    class="fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-dot-event fc-event fc-event-draggable fc-event-resizable fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-past fullcalendar_nearest_days"
                    data-id="undefined"><span class="flex flex-nowrap"><
```

Can it be that properties of fullcalendar_nearest_days are not applied as they are overwritten by fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-dot-event fc-event fc-event-draggable fc-event-resizable fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-past ?
Can I remove all/part of these classes in "a" tag class definition for some dates?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the CSS definition of `fullcalendar_nearest_days`?

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo using your CSS - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYwYxRp . There doesn't seem to be a problem for timed events, the class is applied to the correct events and the colours change as you'd expect.

However on all-day events the yellow colour is not applied. If you use the element inspector in your browser you can see what CSS rules are applied to each element and what is overriding them. You can see that the title is inside another div within the main element, which has fc-event-main class on it, and that class has a rule which overrides the `color` property again.

Fortunately we can solve this easily by adjusting the CSS rule to deal with that situation specifically:

```
.fullcalendar_nearest_days, .fullcalendar_nearest_days .fc-event-main {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: yellow !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJmJPEP